# how to print cells of a table with simple html dom

Tags: php, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

i have this html code. Im using Simple HTML Dom to parse the data into my own php script.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="header">Name</td>
        <td class="header">City</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="text">Greg House</td>
        <td class="text">Century City</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="text">Dexter Morgan</td>
        <td class="text">Miami</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I need to get the text inside the TDs in an array, example:

$array[0] = array('Greg House','Century City');
$array[1] = array('Dexter Morgan','Miami');

I've tried several ways to get that but i've fail in each and everyone of them. Can someone give me a hand?

Comment: You should use [DOM and Xpath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019422/regex-problem-in-php)

Comment: i have to do it using Simple HTML Dom ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should do:

```
// get the table. Maybe there's just one, in which case just 'table' will do
$table = $html->find('#theTable');

// initialize empty array to store the data array from each row
$theData = array();

// loop over rows
foreach($table->find('tr') as $row) {

    // initialize array to store the cell data from each row
    $rowData = array();
    foreach($row->find('td.text') as $cell) {

        // push the cell's text to the array
        $rowData[] = $cell->innertext;
    }

    // push the row's data array to the 'big' array
    $theData[] = $rowData;
}
print_r($theData);
```

Comment: @andufo,@Karim, Can you please tell me how you make object($html) in dom object. So you have used it as:- $table = $html->find('#theTable');

Answer (score 7):

**It will work.. try this**

```
 include('simple_html_dom.php');
 $html = file_get_html('mytable.html');
 foreach($html->find('table tr td') as $e){
    $arr[] = trim($e->innertext);
  }

 print_r($arr);
```

You can get data from any html tag even attributes too...

Answer (score 2):

@lucia nie

You should do this so:

```
// initialize empty array to store the data array from each row
$theData = array();

// loop over rows
foreach($html->find('#theTable tr') as $row) {

// initialize array to store the cell data from each row
$rowData = array();
foreach($row->find('td.text') as $cell) {

    // push the cell's text to the array
    $rowData[] = $cell->innertext;
}

// push the row's data array to the 'big' array
$theData[] = $rowData;
}
print_r($theData);
```