# Parse HTML table into multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, html-parsing

I'd like to store images (which are in tables) in a multidimensional array, grouped **according to their table** and their descriptions, so that later when I call the images, I can display them accordingly.  For example, say I have two tables, one with three images, and another with one.

I'd like the resulting array to look like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => image1.jpg
            [1] => 1st Variation Description
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => image2.jpg
            [1] => image3.jpg
            [2] => image4.jpg
            [3] => 2nd Variation Description
        )

)
```

*Edit* Thanks for the recommendations on the Simple HTML Dom Parser.  Here's what I've done so far, and I've reached a bit of a plateau as to how to store the data in the exact structure I need.

```
$html = str_get_html($vartables);   
$varinfo = array();
foreach($html->find('table') as $table){
        $varinfo[] = $table->innertext;
}
print_r($varinfo);
```

This gives me something to the effect of:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
 <tr>
  <td width=150>
Description1
 </td>

 <td><a href="image1.jpg">
<img src="image1" height=100 border=1></a>
  </td>
 </tr>

    [1] => 
 <tr>
  <td width=150>
Description2
  </td>

<td><a href="image2.jpg">
<img src="image2.jpg" height=200 border=1></a>
  </td>
  <td><a href="image3.jpg">
<img src="image3.jpg" height=200 border=1></a>

  </td>
 <td><a href="image4.jpg">
<img src="image4.jpg" height=200 border=1></a>
  </td>
 </tr>

)
```

I'd like to strip out the html and keep the .jpg's and descriptions together in a multidimensional array...unfortunately my newbness is getting the better of me there, I'm researching but running into a roadblock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found similar problem here and was able to adapt the answer: [how to print cells of a table with simple html dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277687/how-to-print-cells-of-a-table-with-simple-html-dom)

The only difference from my original structure being that the description is the first value in an array instead of the last, which is better I think.

```
$html = str_get_html($vartables);

$html = str_get_html($vartables);   
$theData = array();

foreach($html->find('table') as $onetable){
foreach($onetable->find('tr') as $row) {

    $rowData = array();
    foreach($row->find('td') as $cell) {
        if(substr_count($cell->innertext,"src")>0){
        foreach($cell->find('img') as $element) {
        $rowData[] = $element->src;
        }
        }else{
        $rowData[] = $cell->innertext;
        }
    }

    $theData[] = $rowData;
}
}

print_r($theData);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Description1
            [1] => image1.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Description2
            [1] => image2.jpg
            [2] => image3.jpg
            [3] => image4.jpg
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try use [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) or another framework for parsing HTML.

Comment: Yes, but I wouldn't be sure how to implement them.  I edited my post showing the different things I actually know how to do with the DOM element to parse the HTML, but I don't have any skills beyond that.  If someone could show me how, I'd be most grateful.

Comment: If anyone can help me with how to enter the data into a multidimensional array structure, that's the part I'm having the most issues with.

Comment: Found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277687/how-to-print-cells-of-a-table-with-simple-html-dom, and I'll post how I adapted it once the 24 hour limit is up. :)