# Regex PHP to get data from a website

Tags: php, regex

I want to scrap following data( pink color part in image )  from http://www.kitco.com/market/

[image]

I was able to scrap data from The World Spot Price - Asia/Europe/NY markets HTML Table below that table using  following.. but not able to get the London Fix data.. what changes should i do in the regular expression below as i tried many combinations but it doesnt work

My code looks like the following

```
$html= get_url_contents("http://www.kitco.com/market/");
//echo $html;


preg_match_all('!Gold\s+([0-9.]+)\s+([0-9.]+)!i',$html,$matches);

$patt = "/<td[^>]*width=['\"]68['\"][^>]*>([0-9\.]+)<\/td>\s*<td[^>]*width=['\"]68['\"][^>]*>([0-9\.]+)<\/td>/i";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do not parse HTML with regular expressions (you can see why in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) mandatory post).

That being said, you can use an HTML parser, such as the [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to process the table. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277687/how-to-print-cells-of-a-table-with-simple-html-dom) previous SO post to get started in the right direction.

EDIT: As per your comment, you could try to do something like so: `<td bgcolor=".+?">\s*<p>\s*(.+?)\s*</p>\s*</td>`. I do however, advise ***against*** this approach.

This will match and put the values into regex groups, which you can then, later access.

NOTE: Also as per your comment, the regex you propose is also susceptible style changes, so if they change the `width` of the columns, your regex will most likely fail.

Comment: but regex works great for me .. i already parsed the other table using that

Comment: @user580950: I have amended my answer to include a regular expression. However, like I said in my response, this is ***not*** the (right) way to go.